# Solving java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.criterion.CriteriaQuery.getFactory()

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have the following hibernate query:

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<Admin> getAffectedAdmins(String wktFilter) {
        WKTReader fromText = new WKTReader();
        Geometry filter = null;

        try {
            filter = fromText.read(wktFilter);
            System.out.println("Filter = " + filter);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        hibernateTemplate = new HibernateTemplate(sessionFactory);
        List<Admin> admins = new ArrayList<Admin>();
        admins =  (List<Admin>) hibernateTemplate.findByCriteria(
                DetachedCriteria.forClass(Admin.class)
                .add(SpatialRestrictions.intersects("geom", filter)));

        return admins;
    }
```

When I execute the above method, the following exception is thrown:

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.criterion.CriteriaQuery.getFactory()Lorg/hibernate/engine/spi/SessionFactoryImplementor;`

The relevant section in my spring configuration file is shown below:

```
    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
        p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close"
        p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
        p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}"
        p:password="${jdbc.password}" />


    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
        <property name="configurationClass">
            <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
```

My environment: Hibernate-3.6.10.FINAL, Spring 3.1.2.RELEASE, Hibernate Spatial 4.x, PostGIS JDBC 1.5.2 and PostgreSQL 8.4-702.jdbc3.

Any idea on what I may be doing wrong will be highly appreciated.

**UPDATE**: This works for simple queries; queries that do not involve spatial data. So, I guess its the spatial component that has issues.

UPDATE: pom.xml, I've included the relevant sections in my POM file.

```
<properties>
        <spring.version>3.1.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-spatial</artifactId>
            <version>4.0-M1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgis</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgis-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-spatial.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>postgis-jdbc</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.postgis</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions> 
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgis</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgis-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>8.4-702.jdbc3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.1</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Try executing simplest query and see if error still exists.

Comment: to me it looks like jar conflict. Where it fails - server or junit? and which server its deployed, if? more info..

Comment: @JMelnik, this works fine with simple queries; the ones without spatial components. This has led me to the conclusion that it's the spatial components that has issues.

Comment: @JIV, it fails when the method is executed. Deployment is on tomcat 7.0.27, but this proceeds successfully. I'm updating the question to include my POM file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My environment: Hibernate-3.6.10.FINAL, Hibernate Spatial 4.x

But http://www.hibernatespatial.org/:

> Compatibility with Hibernate ORM

```
Hibernate Spatial version 1.0 is compatible with Hibernate 3.2.x - 3.5.x
Hibernate Spatial version 1.1.x is compatible with Hibernate 3.6.x
Hibernate Spatial version 4.0 is compatible with Hibernate 4.x
```

Comment: Thanks, @Vadzim, for this pointer. I'm going to effect the changes and try it out in a few minutes.

Comment: I've updated the versions in the pom.xml. Now the sessionFactory cannot be created, thus the app cannot be deployed. I'll have to give this a look again later in the day. I'll post my findings then.

Comment: Thanks. It finally worked after this, among a host of other changes. It was quite a challenge getting Hibernate Spatial 4.x to work with the rest. I'll prepare a post on this.